# Java String to Double

Tags: java, string, double, converters

I recently began to program in Java, and i ran into a little problem:

I already made a String to Double line, but it doesn't seems to work proberly. As you see, the string I want to convert into a Double is one of following: `USD`, `GPB` and `EURO`. I know you can't convert text into a Double, but I already told Java the values of the Strings.

When I run the program below, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "usd" at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source) at Valuta.main(Valuta.java:22)

Why does that happen?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Valuta {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double euro, usd, gpb, done;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        euro = 7.46;
        usd = 5.56;
        gpb = 8.84;

        System.out.println("DKK to ??");
        System.out.println("USD,GPB or EURO?");
        String temp = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("amount of dkk??");
        Double dkk = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("mhm");
        double donee = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        done = dkk*donee;
        System.out.println(done);
```

Comment: is the issue floating arithmetic?

Comment: What `doesnt seems to work proberly` ?

Comment: sorry for caps, but DO NOT USE FLOAT OR DOUBLE FOR CURRENCY!!!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "usd"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Valuta.main(Valuta.java:22)

Comment: you are trying parse wrong string, you fill your `temp` value with currency code not with value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to be able to associate user input for `System.out.println("USD,GPB or EURO?");` to

```
    euro = 7.46;
    usd = 5.56;
    gpb = 8.84;
```

One of hte ways to do it is to create a look up `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Double> lookUpMap = new HashMap<String, Double>(){{
put("EURO", new Double(7.46));
put("USD", new Double(5.56));
put("GPB", new Double(8.84));
}};
```

Then parse user input and look up `Double` value:

```
lookUpMap.get(userInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you parse the *currency* as a *double* input. This line:

```
  double donee = Double.parseDouble(temp);
```

should be *select* the proper conversion factor for the currency. You can do that with a simple if/else, a map or whatever:

```
  double donee;
  if ("usd".equalsIgnoreCase(temp) {
      donee = usd;
  } else if ("gbp".equalsIgnoreCase(temp)) {
      donee = gbp;
  /* more cases ... */
  } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("unknown currency");
  }
```

You probably should move that *up* to *before* you get the number input, since if it causes an error the number input can't be processed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems in this program. First to fix you're error you need to declare type `double` for the `USD, GBP, and EURO` variable names that you have there. Second you are going to need to do an `if else if else` block to determine what conversion to do.

```
double total;
if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")){
  total = dkk*usd;
}else if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP"){
  total = dkk*gbp;
}else {
  total = dkk*euro;
}
System.out.println("This is your converted total " + total);
```

That will do the conversion that you want it to do. You should also take out Double.parseDouble(temp) because turning that string into a double isn't going to help you.